# Why are my stacked bars not being deleted when my graph changes in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-chart

I'm working with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eWN52/).  I expect that when I click the `WeekView` button it should change the bar colors to reflect the same colors that are in my legend.  But for some reason the colors are different.

I don't think

```
var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(stack);

layer.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .style("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color(i);
});

layer.exit()
    .remove();
```

is being called when I switch to weekview, therefore its not replacing the old bars with the new ones its just reusing the bars from the previous views.

How can I get d3.js to replace the bars with the proper colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the problem is in that part of the code: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eWN52/1/)

```js
var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(stack);

layer.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer");

// Set the colors in the `update` cycle, not the `enter` cycle.
layer.style("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color(i);
});

layer.exit()
    .remove();
```

There is an interesting history of why this behaves this way. In earlier versions of D3, the `enter` and `update` set of elements were kept separate, just like `update` and `exit` events are still kept separate, i.e. operations you performed on the `update` set would not be performed on the `exit` set and vice-versa.

However, [in version 2.0 of D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases/tag/v2.0.0), it was decided that any element appended in the `enter` phase would also become a part of the `update` set. This was done because often the `enter` set of elements and the `update` set of elements needed to have the exact same operation performed on them (like in your case). To avoid this effect, you'll need to write the `update` phase *before* the `enter` phase.

Hence, in the `enter` cycle, elements should be `appended` and their *initial* attributes should should be set while their *final* values (which they should have in *static* state) should be set in the `update` cycle.

Comment: Thank you for a great question; I love histories of evolution of software. :)